# Detox android test references incorrect Android SDK path. "There was no "aapt" executable file in directory"

Tags: android, sdk, detox, aapt

I have a React Native app up and running, and have Detox installed and working for iOS, but having issues running the test for Android. When I run the test, I get the following error:

```
There was no "aapt" executable file in directory: /Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/30.0.3.
```

There seems to be some duplication in that referenced path, but `Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/30.0.3` definitely exists. I'm not sure where this path is being referenced, or any config changes I can make to Detox to reference the SDK path correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error seemed to have been caused by an incorrect installation of the 30.0.3 SDK Build Tools. I simply uninstalled it and everything appears to be working fine now.

In Android Studio -> Tools -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools -> check "Show Package Details" -> uncheck the version you want to remove -> Apply